# Iterate over the packets read in WinDivertReceiveEx in batch- Divert lib

Tags: c++, c, windows

How to iterate over the each packet on the buffer received from WinDivertReceiveEx call, when the bytes are stored contiguously without delimiter? Is there any example which I can refer.

https://reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html#divert_recv_ex

https://github.com/basil00/Divert

> The received packets are packed contiguously (i.e., no gaps) into the
> pPacket buffer.

This is from the documentation.

Comment: I think [WinDivertHelperParsePacket()](https://reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html#divert_helper_parse_packet) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes it will help in parse the packet. Only limitation is need to do deep packet inspection with various ethertype. 
Discussed in detail in this thread. - https://github.com/basil00/Divert/issues/325

Comment: The packets are variable length, and the API doesn't provide their lengths, so the only option is to parse them to determine their lengths. You could do your own minimal parsing just to determine the lengths and split the packets, then some other code could do deeper parsing.

Comment: Yeah. thankq. I tried with this approach. it is working. only limitation is need to write code for all possible ether types.